# filter non-nested tag values from XML

Tags: python, python-3.x, xml, beautifulsoup

I have an xml that looks like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main_heading timestamp="20220113">
<details>
    <offer id="11" parent_id="12">
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <pos>697</pos>
        <kat_pis>
            <pos kat="2">112</pos>
        </kat_pis>
    </offer>
    <offer id="12" parent_id="31">
        <name>Beta</name>
        <pos>099</pos>
        <kat_pis>
            <pos kat="2">113</pos>
        </kat_pis>
    </offer>
</details>
</main_heading>
```

I am parsing it using BeautifulSoup. Upon doing this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(file, 'xml')

pos = []
for i in (soup.find_all('pos')):
    pos.append(i.text)
```

I get a list of all **POS** tag values, even the ones that are nested within the tag **kat_pis**.

So I get (697, 112, 099. 113).

However, I only want to get the POS values of the non-nested tags.

**Expected desired result is (697, 099).**

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of getting those first level `pos`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

xml_doc = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<main_heading timestamp="20220113">
<details>
    <offer id="11" parent_id="12">
        <name>Alpha</name>
        <pos>697</pos>
        <kat_pis>
            <pos kat="2">112</pos>
        </kat_pis>
    </offer>
    <offer id="12" parent_id="31">
        <name>Beta</name>
        <pos>099</pos>
        <kat_pis>
            <pos kat="2">113</pos>
        </kat_pis>
    </offer>
</details>
</main_heading>'''

soup = bs(xml_doc, 'xml')

pos = []
for i in (soup.select('offer > pos')):
    pos.append(i.text)

print(pos)
```

Result in terminal:

```
['697', '099']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the best solution would be to abandon BeautifulSoup for an XML parser with XPath support, like [`lxml`](https://lxml.de/). Using XPath expressions, you can ask for only those `tos` elements that are children of `offer` elements:

```
from lxml import etree

with open('data.xml') as fd:
    doc = etree.parse(fd)

pos = []
for ele in (doc.xpath('//offer/pos')):
    pos.append(ele.text)

print(pos)
```

Given your example input, the above code prints:

```
['697', '099']
```